# java ee background service

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

You'll have to excuse me if I'm describing this incorrectly, but essentially I'm trying to get a service-like class to be instantiated just once at server start and to sort of "exist" in the background until it is killed off at server stop. At least from what I can tell, this is not exactly the same as a typical servlet (though I may be wrong about this). What's even more important is that I need to also be able to access this service/object later down the line.

As an example, in another project I've worked on, we used the Spring Framework to accomplish something similar. Essentially, we used the configuration XML file along with the built-in annotations to let Spring know to instantiate instances of some of our services. Later down the line, we used the annotation @Autowired to sort of "grab" the object reference of this pre-instantiated service/object.

So, though it may seem against some of the major concepts of Java itself, I'm just trying to figure out how to reinvent this wheel here. I guess sometimes I feel like these big app frameworks do too much "black-box magic" behind the scenes that I'd really like to be able to fine-tune.

Thanks for any help and/or suggestions!

---

Oh and I'm trying to run this all from JBoss 6

Comment: In what way is Spring's IOC and autowiring NOT what you want?  It lets you create a singleton that any other class can get to.

Comment: my guess there is no Spring in his current project. adding Spring for a singleton only would be an overkill, IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Add a servlet context listener to your `web.xml`, e.g.:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.BackgroundServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then create that class to manage your background service. In this example I use a single-threaded `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule it to run every 5 minutes:

```
public class BackgroundServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    private BackgroundService service;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        service = new BackgroundService();

        // setup single thread to run background service every 5 minutes
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(service, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        // make the background service available to the servlet context
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("service", service);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

public class BackgroundService implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do your background processing here
    }
}
```

If you need to access the `BackgroundService` from web requests, you can access it through the `ServletContext`. E.g.:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
BackgroundService service = (BackgroundService) context.getAttribute("service");
```

Comment: This is pretty intuitive..I had crossed paths with the notion of implementing a context listener, and I just didn't know how to make the service available to other parts of the web app. The context.setAttribute() seems like it should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This is very helpful. I am wondering if it could be used on JBoss AS 5.1.0? I am unable to find a ServletContextListener built into this version... If I add "jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar" from a JBoss 7.1 download to the lib or build path I can use javax.servlet, but I'm sure this will cause some compatibility issues. Is there a good alternative in 5.1?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using an EJB 3.1 Session bean? These can be deployed in a war file, and can be annotated with @Singleton and @Startup.

A number of annotations available with EJB 3.1 are designed to bring Spring goodies into the Java EE framework. It may be the re-invention you're considering has been done for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `messaging` for that. Just send message to the `queue`, and let the `message listener` do the processing `asynchronously in the background`.
You can use `JMS` for the implementation, and `ActiveMQ` for the message broker.
Spring has `JMSTemplate`, `JMSGateWaySupport` API to make JMS Implementation simple

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

Answer (score 0):

If you must roll your own, you can create a servlet and configure it start up when the application does using [load-on-startup](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/166-load-on-startup-element-in-webxml.html).  I built a system like that a few years ago.  We then used the new(ish) java.util.concurrent stuff like [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to have it process work from other servlets.

More information about what you're trying to do, and why the existing ways of doing things is insufficient, would be helpful.